# Excel - Data Source from SQL Server just using temp tables / variables

Tags: sql-server, excel, odbc

I get many ad hoc requests for analysis which I do in SQL Server, and then I deliver the results in Excel as a table or pivot.  These reports are refreshable for the user by saving the SQL in the connection.

In some cases, the analysis requires several layers of joins and would be too time consuming to run with one SQL statement.  When I create a temp table, the analysis runs in an acceptable amount of time, however when I then create the connection with the temp table, I get an error "Problems obtaining data".

When I create a stored proc from that same SQL with the temp table, Excel is able retrieve the results.  This is not an optimal solution however, as I would end up with many stored procs in my db over time.  I've tried temp tables and table variables but neither worked.  Why is it that simply encapsulating this SQL in a stored proc allows Excel to process the results?

Is there a solution out there which would allow me to create ad hoc SQL in excel without the need to pollute my db with stored procs that answer ad hoc questions?  I'd like to avoid VBA, because I'm trying to keep this process as lightweight as possible.

Comment: You realise a temp table/variable only exist within the current session - i.e. the session that created them? Perhaps *Views* are what you are looking for.

Comment: How about creating an SP *from Excel*, run it, then drop it *from Excel*?

Comment: Alex, I don't understand how your comment is relevant.  When Excel is running the SQL commands stored in the connection that is a single session and the temp / variable tables "should be" usable.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to the top of your SQL Query:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

that should do the job.